# How to change contents of a file in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, aix

I am creating a script `script1.sh` through which I have to change an xml file(`abc.xml`) contents. The contents of xml file are

```
area = xyz/a
url = "sqlserver://servername:portno/a"
username=""
password=""

area = xyz/b
url = "sqlserver://servername:portno/b"
username=""
password=""
```

I have to change `servername`, `portno`, `username` and `password` for both area using `script1.sh`.
`Servername` and `portno` will be same for both area but `username` and `password` will differ. So how can I make changes from `script1.sh` to `abc.xml`

```
sed -i 's/$strurl/$url/g' context.sh
```

This is how I am searching but can't search and change url rest all are fine. I think the url string is too big to be searched.

Comment: `awk` and `perl` both seem like reasonable tools. What have you tried? Where are the replacements coming from, and how does it know which username/password goes with which area?

Comment: That doesn't look like XML. Is what you're posting really the contents of the file?

Comment: I used sed but all the username and password are getting the same value

Comment: Explain in more detail what you did, please

Comment: I had edited above with what I did.

Comment: @Joni It is not the whole XML part I had shown you the part which I have to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed -i 's!$strurl!$url!g' filename`

This will be the answer as url itself contains '/' as separator so we need to use some other separator inside sed command

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` with option `-i` to change a file in-place.

```
sed -i 's/what/towhat/g' filename.txt
```

In case your `what` contains slashes (`/`) itself, use any other character (e. g. `,`) which does not appear in the `what` or the `towhat`.

Comment: I know this step but I can't search and change url with this command, url is too big to be searched.

Comment: Your URL wasn't too big to be searched.  You can use any command delimiter in case your URL contains slashes (`/`).